# bokeh: How to export a grid to png with given size?

Tags: bokeh

I prepared some bokeh plots to display as html.

To this end I prepared a `gridplot` containing the subplots, the legends and some headings. This all displays extremely nice in HTML and with `sizing_mode='stretch_width'` it's even kind of responsive.

```
webpage = gridplot([[header_col],[panel_grid_plot]], toolbar_location=None, sizing_mode='stretch_width')
show(webpage)
```

Now I also want to export this "webpage" to a PNG. To this end, I use

```
export_png(webpage, filename= png_filename, width=1800)
```

Unfortunately, the `width` parameter is ignored as the `webpage` is an object of type `gridbox` and not of type `Plot`. (This is checked in the bokeh/io/export.py in the method def `get_layout_html()`)

The output is a png of a width of 800px which is kind of useless as the actual information is crushed (while the legends are nicely scaled):
[image]

Any ideas how to set the width of my PNG export to useful values?

Is there a way to convert a `gridbox`to a `Plot`?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should've received a warning saying that the width argument will be ignored since you're passing into `export_png` something that's not a plot.

A way of achieving what you want:

```py
webpage = gridplot(..., sizing_mode='stretch_width')
webpage.width = 1800
export_png(webpage)
```